# Graph API - Get count for Mailfolder Sent Items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I was able to get the count number of emails from Inbox with this request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2017-04-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2017-05-01 & count=true`, but i also want to get the same result from the Sent folder but the filter "ReceivedDateTime" only exists for inbox and i couldn't seem to find something of equal for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$filter= XXXXX & count=true`, is there way to accomplish the same way with Inbox? or i have to apply a workaround for this? Would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Edit:
I didn't explain myself right, while I'm able to get a result for the request the return count is 0.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please share more details, it's not clear which query fails and what is the error. Btw. this query works fine for me https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/sentItems/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2017-04-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2017-05-01&count=true

Comment: @user2250152 the query for Sent Items gives me a count of 0 when in truth there's more then that. The filter parameter "receivedDateTime" I think it only works for the Inbox, as per it's name, since it gives me a correct result for that and not for Sent Items

Comment: have you tried using sentDateTime ? the receivedDateTime should work okay with sentItems it should be set to the time the mailbox received the copy of the Sent Item. I have seen this property get affected by migration apps (but it usually just the creation time). What do you see set in the datetime properties if you just list the messages using the Messages collection? (try filtering on the subject of a message you know is within that time period so you can check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

To get count for **Mailfolder Sent Items**, I used the below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages?$filter=sentDateTime ge 2023-02-01T10:48:32Z and sentDateTime lt 2023-03-02T10:48:32Z&$count=true
```

I am able to get the **count** successfully as below:

[image]

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('a970fc40-48da-4ac7-b126-b402066xxxxx')/mailFolders('SentItems')/messages",
"@odata.count": 1,
"value": [
{
"@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAADnuLg\"",
"id": "AAMkADM1NzUwMTUxLWJlZjQtNDFkYi1iNGRjLWE0ODllYTlkN2YxNABGAAAAAACBV9bfhcIjToPFQy4MncjpBwCzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAAAAAEJAACzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAADn_mdAAA=",
"createdDateTime": "2023-03-01T10:48:02Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-01T10:48:35Z",
"changeKey": "CQAAABYAAACzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAADnuLg",
"categories": [],
"receivedDateTime": "2023-03-01T10:48:33Z",
"sentDateTime": "2023-03-01T10:48:32Z",
"hasAttachments": false,
"internetMessageId": "<DM6PR08MB6028DE02B9748EAE2F6B52CBE8AD9@DM6PR08MB6028.namprd08.prod.outlook.com>",
"subject": "Demo purpose",
"bodyPreview": "Hi",
"importance": "normal",
"parentFolderId": AQMkADM1NzUwMTUxLWJlZjQtNDFkYi1iNGRjLWE0ODllYTlkN2YxNAAuAAADgVfW34XCI06DxUMuDJ3I6QEAs8hj4slJ2Uym2iEo0LZgVgAAAgEJAAAA",
"conversationId": "AAQkADM1NzUwMTUxLWJlZjQtNDFkYi1iNGRjLWE0ODllYTlkN2YxNAAQAJ8H6HcWuYdKrpnWkNhuETw=",
"conversationIndex": "AQHZTCtLnwfodxa5h0qumdaQ2G4RPA==",
"isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
"isReadReceiptRequested": false,
"isRead": true,
"isDraft": false,
"webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADM1NzUwMTUxLWJlZjQtNDFkYi1iNGRjLWE0ODllYTlkN2YxNABGAAAAAACBV9bfhcIjToPFQy4MncjpBwCzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAAAAAEJAACzyGPiyUnZTKbaISjQtmBWAAADn%2BmdAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
"inferenceClassification": "focused",
"body": {
"contentType": "html",
"content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\"><!--p{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}--></style></head><body dir=\"ltr\"><div class=\"elementToProof\" style=\"font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0); background-color:rgb(255,255,255)\">Hi Sri</div></body></html>"
},
"sender": {
"emailAddress": {
"name": "user1",
"address": "user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
},
"from": {
"emailAddress": {
"name": "user1",
"address": "user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"name": "xxx@microsoft.com",
"address": "xxx@microsoft.com"
}
}
],
"ccRecipients": [],
"bccRecipients": [],
"replyTo": [],
"flag": {
"flagStatus": "notFlagged"
}
}
]
}
```

- The issue usually occurs if there are no sent items in the given time range filter.
- Make sure to use **`SentDateTime`** in the filter.
- The messages date and time are included in the `SentDateTime` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I wasn't informed that it was a shared mailbox and it didn't keep a copy when sent on behalf. So I can use receivedDateTime or sentDateTime as filter ?

Comment: Try using receivedDateTime filter and check.